# Is there an equivalant in c# for Delphi's "stored = false" property clause

Tags: c#, delphi, properties

In Delphi there you can add a clause to a property that will make sure the value if this property will never get written in its `.dfm` file.
The `.dfm` file is about the same as the `.designer.cs` file in c#

Can this also be done in c# ?

A usefull example would be the connected property on an connection object.
By not storing this in the designer file it does not matters if a developer would leave it connected in design time, at runtime it will be not connected anyway because the `connected = true` value will not be in the designer file.

In Delphi it looks like this :

```
type
  TggAdoConnection = class(TADOConnection)
  published
    property Connected stored false;
  end;
```

So how can this be done in c# ?

Comment: @Victoria That looks very promising thank you. I searched for this but sometimes you just need to use the right search key words